# What are the rules about interacting with Spanish police?

Tags: legal, spain, cultural-awareness

Good evening!

I am an American, due to travel to Spain sometime next month. This will be my first trip to the country, and I will be travelling with passengers. I'm curious to know, what the expectations are when dealing with local and national police in Spain.

Specifically, things like:

- If detained by authorities and asked for identification, do I need to provide it? Will I need to use a passport, or will another form of ID (such as my Colorado driver's license) suffice? Will they even ask, or just expect ID to be provided?
- If a police officer initiates a traffic stop on me/my vehicle, should I remain in my vehicle or should I exit the vehicle and walk to the police officer?
- If I am asked a question by an officer, should I answer it or remain silent?

Comment: What is your end goal?  To enjoy your holiday, or to get arrested and thrown in jail for a day or two?

Comment: I don't see why you would do anything other than what you would normally do interacting with law enforcement anywhere: Be polite; be respectful; answer questions promptly; don't do anything or volunteer any information they don't ask for.

Comment: @GregHewgill, there are varying expectations for how you interact with the police.  For example, there are countries where you can pay a traffic ticket on the spot; in the US, attempting to do so would look uncomfortably like an attempt to bribe the officer.

Comment: IMO the Spanish police are used to dealing with clueless foreigners, no need to worry too much. If there is a possibility to pay a fine on the spot, they'll tell you. Same is true for other questions.

Comment: Ad driving licenses: https://www.americansinbarcelona.com/driving-in-spain-with-us-license/

Comment: There are many police related questions asked on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=Police%20is%3aq&searchOn=3). I don't believe that someone tells you to be ready to pribe a police officer in a Western European country. I personally don't understand how the right to remain silent improves anything in case you are interrupted by police.

Comment: Unfortunately, it depends on your race, age, overt religion, if you're drunk, on drugs, or sober, and whether you're dressed in a suit and tie or a tracksuit covered in marijuana leaves. And precisely where you are: most police in tourist resorts are used to dealing with tourists, although there are occasional crackdowns. Spanish police are no worse than most countries.

Comment: @Mark: Trying to pay a ticket on the spot in the US would be "doing something the officer didn't ask for".

Comment: @Doc to enjoy the holiday